# Sequelize optional relation

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to create optional relation? for ex.

I have 2 tables:
- User (id, siteId, email, ...), can have multiple users with same email
- Wallet (id, email, ...), one Wallet per email address

I want to be able find all Users by Wallet object (by its email)
I want to be able find the Wallet by User record

Not every email address has Wallet, so that means that sometimes users has Wallet, and sometimes no.

What are the relation that I have to set on Sequelize in order to achive that goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by adding `constraints: false` to the belongsTo and hasMany

Answer (score 0):

Settings `constraints: false` works but it doesn't create the foreign key so you lose the relation between two tables.

Please see the answer below for better way of handling this requirement
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68068079/5219165